# Pythonic way to know when / why my threads exited

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.6

**Context:** 
I have a script, which runs indefinitely, that monitors a simple queue of urls that need to be downloaded.  If a url enters the queue, the script checks if its already spawned a thread for that url and if it hasn't, it spawns a thread who's job is to fetch data from that url periodically until the url returns it a 404 (which I know will happen because the urls are only available for a specified period of time) at which point, it will call `sys.exit` to raise a `SystemExit` exception and essentially mark itself for termination as I understand it.

**Question:** I would like to be able to log the specific time when the thread exits, even if it exits for some other reason besides my call to `sys.exit` and gather as much meta data about why it exited as possible.  What is the best way to do this?  Do threads pass info to the parent who spawned them when they exit?

**Code:**

A simplified example of the code

```
    class MyThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, sF, id):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.sourceFile = [sF]
            self.id = id 

        def run(self): 
            #do stuff until i encounter a 404, at which point, I'll call sys.exit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True: 
        #logic to check the queue, if there is a new url, spawn a new Thread
        #for each new thread in the queue: 
            t = MyThread(file, i)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
import datetime

class MyThread(threading.Thread)
    termination_cause = None
    termination_time = None

    #snip

    def run(self):
        try:
            # do stuff
        except Exception as e:  # I wouldn't recommend this, but you asked for it
            self.termination_cause = e  # If an Exception occurred, it will be here
        finally:
            self.termination_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

As soon as you exit the `try` block, either because an `Exception` was raised or because the block ended, then the `finally` block will execute, and the `termination_time` attribute will be set.

---

Note that I wouldn't consider it good practice to raise a `SystemExit` to close your thread. Why don't you just the block flow to its end?

```
def run(self):
    try:
        while 1:
            if url_returns_404(url):
                break
            # do my thing with the URL
    finally:
        self.termination_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Cool.  this covers the when.  Would the why be covered by sys.exc_info() or is there something else I should know going down this route?

Comment: Your edit says you wouldn't recommend the Exception part.  I don't fully understand why?  If something unexpected occurs, I'm going to want to know what it was?

Comment: @Brad You're right: get more info (more precisely, you'll get the traceback), if you use `sys.exc_info()` and not `e` there

Comment: @Brad Every time I used `except Exception`, I've regretted it down the road. In general, it makes debugging a lot harder, because you'll forget it's there, and then an `Exception` you didn't even think existed gets trapped in there. If you `except Exception`, add a `logging.exception("I died! Here's my traceback")` statement there ; ) That's a decent middle-of-the-road approach.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I was going to do. Thanks!